# Adding links to crossfaded images css

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following HTML:

```
<div class="crossfade_container">
  <div id="crossfade">
      **<a href="#">**<img src="osu_crossfade1.png" alt="Ohio State Cheerleaders waving OHIO flags" />**</a>**
      **<a href="#">**<a href="#"><img src="um_huddle1.png" alt="Michigan Players in team Huddle" />**</a>**
      **<a href="#">**<img src="osu_crossfade2.png" alt="Overlooking Independence Hall from Ohio Stadium" />**</a>**
      **<a href="#">**<img src="um_qb1.png" alt="Devin Gardner Scrambles out of the pocket" />**</a>**
      **<a href="#">**<img src="osu_crossfade3.png" alt="Ohio Stadium on Gameday" />**</a>**
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.crossfade_container {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;

    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 695px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 10px;

    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px silver;
  }
  #crossfade > **a** img { 
    width: 695px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s; 
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
    -o-animation-delay: 8s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-delay: 8s; 
  }
  #crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
    -o-animation-delay: 16s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
    animation-delay: 16s; 
  }
  #crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
  }
  #crossfade > img:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 32s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 32s;
    -o-animation-delay: 32s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 32s;
    animation-delay: 32s; 
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    5% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }
```

I would like to add  to surround the crossfaded images so they are able to be links and not just images. However, whenever do so, it destroys the css I have in place. thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you please provide `destroyed` version please.

Comment: Try This - http://jsfiddle.net/sL3ke3f1/

Comment: @MaryMelody did you just add the "a href"'s to the HTML code and remove the ">" from the css code??

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin Its not like I removed the `">"` from the css code, In my demo the space between `#crossfade img` elements is the [descendant selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) and thats my original fiddle and I didn't edit it.

Comment: @MaryMelody  this seems to cycle through my images very quickly and ending the crossfade cycle after 1-2 seconds, just like the code listed below...

Comment: @MaryMelody if you change the images to be different in the jsfiddle, you will see what i am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to remove or update all `>` CSS declarations: `>` indicates a direct child and no longer works because `img` is now a child of `a`, not a direct descendent of `#crossfade`. See updated code block below which adds `a` before `img` which translates to "direct descendent of #crossfade a, descendent img of a".

```
.crossfade_container {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;

    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 695px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 10px;

    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px silver;
  }
  #crossfade > a img { 
    width: 695px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s; 
  }

  #crossfade > a img:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
    -o-animation-delay: 8s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-delay: 8s; 
  }
  #crossfade > a img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
    -o-animation-delay: 16s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
    animation-delay: 16s; 
  }
  #crossfade > a img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
  }
  #crossfade > a img:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 32s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 32s;
    -o-animation-delay: 32s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 32s;
    animation-delay: 32s; 
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    5% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }
```

What happens if you update all `img` instances to your `a` container element?

```
.crossfade_container {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;

    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 695px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 10px;

    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px silver;
  }
  #crossfade > a { 
    width: 695px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s; 
  }

  #crossfade > a:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
    -o-animation-delay: 8s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-delay: 8s; 
  }
  #crossfade > a:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
    -o-animation-delay: 16s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
    animation-delay: 16s; 
  }
  #crossfade > a:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
  }
  #crossfade > a:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 32s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 32s;
    -o-animation-delay: 32s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 32s;
    animation-delay: 32s; 
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    5% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }

  @keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
       animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
  }
```

If you aren't opposed to a little jQuery, you could also eliminate all anchor tags and do:

```
<img src="" data-href="http://url.com/" ... />
```

jQuery:

```
$(".crossfade_container img").on( "click", function(){
    window.open( $(this).data("href");
});
```

CSS add the pointer cursor:

```
.crossfade_container img {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: this seems to cycle through my images very quickly and ending the crossfade cycle after 1-2 seconds...

Comment: if you change the images to be different you can see that they are all get cycled through very quickly and do not appear for 8 seconds each. not sure what causes that?

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin what happens if you change all instances of `img` to `a`?

Comment: that looks to have done the trick! Thanks for your help. I went the route of taking out the img tags

Comment: Happy to help! If you don't want to pop links in a new window (some popup blockers will prevent this), you can replace `window.open('url');` with `window.location = 'url';`

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```css
.crossfade_container {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 695px;
  height: 350px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px silver;
}
#crossfade img {
  width: 695px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite 0s;
}
#crossfade img:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
  -o-animation-delay: 8s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
#crossfade img:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
  -o-animation-delay: 16s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
  animation-delay: 16s;
}
#crossfade img:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
#crossfade img:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 32s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 32s;
  -o-animation-delay: 32s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 32s;
  animation-delay: 32s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="crossfade_container">
  <div id="crossfade">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/e3e3e3" alt="Ohio State Cheerleaders waving OHIO flags" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/e3e3e3" alt="Ohio State Cheerleaders waving OHIO flags" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/e3e3e3" alt="Ohio State Cheerleaders waving OHIO flags" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/e3e3e3" alt="Ohio State Cheerleaders waving OHIO flags" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/e3e3e3" alt="Ohio State Cheerleaders waving OHIO flags" />
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you change the images to be different you can see that they are all get cycled through very quickly and do not appear for 8 seconds each. not sure what causes that?